# Angular 5 - Basic timer object not updating in the UI

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on an application built in Angular 5, which needs a basic mm:ss countdown timer, which will eventually be set dynamically. I've tried many different solutions, but all behave in the same way.

I'm starting hard coded just to get it running, and have added a basic function:

```
time: number = 60;
interval;

startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.time > 0) {
            this.time--;
        } else {
            this.time = 60;
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

In the front end, I call the function with a button:

```
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<p>{{ time }} seconds remaining....</p>
```

When the page loads up, the number 60 can be seen. But it doesn't count down. When you press the button, the number changes to whichever second it is up to. So for example it will display 60, click it 2 seconds later and the number will change to 58. So the timer is running the background, but the number is not updating in the UI.

I'm new to Angular, so am probably msising something basic. I've seen other solutions which require creating a Pipe or a subscription, but all those I've tried seem to behave in the same way as this. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to sync the data by [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos: OP isn't using observables at the moment that requires the `async` pipe in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's better to use RxJS instead of `setInterval()` method. Try the following using RxJS `timer` function and `take` and `map` operators.

Controller

```js
timer$: Observable<number>;

startTimer(counter: number) {
  this.timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    take(counter),
    map(_ => --counter)
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<input type="number" #timeInput placeholder="Enter time in seconds"/><br>
<button (click)='startTimer(timeInput.value)'>Start Timer</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="(timer$ | async) as timer">
  <p>{{ timer }} seconds remaining....</p>
</ng-container>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f3xou5?file=src/app/app.component.html)

#### Update: Older version of RxJS (<=v5)

There's a stark difference in the import and usage of RxJS functions and operators b/n v5+ and v6+. The following should work for RxJS v5.

Controller

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

timer$: any;

startTimer(counter: number) {
  this.timer$ = Observable.timer(0, 1000).take(counter).map(_ => --counter);
}
```

Template

```html
<input type="number" #timeInput placeholder="Enter time in seconds"/><br>
<button (click)='startTimer(timeInput.value)'>Start Timer</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="(timer$ | async) as timer">
  <p>{{ timer }} seconds remaining....</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I've tried using RxJS. The problem is the timer is not recognized if you add the import statement import { timer } from "rxjs"; - I assume this is due to is being v5...? I've found this alternate import statement: import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer'; - are they both one and the same?

Comment: @odinel: The syntax is different b/n RxJS 5+ and RxJS 6+. I've updated the answer for RxJS v5.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use RxJs

```js
// imports
import { interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
// inside your component
timeout$: Observable<number>;

setCountdown(time = 60) {
  this.timeout$ = interval(1000).pipe(
    take(time),
    map(t => time - t - 1)
  );
}
```

```html
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<p>{{ timeout$ | async }} seconds remaining....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time > 0) {
        this.time -= 10;
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.time = 60;
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
```